# Android: How to Invoke skype from WebView?

Tags: android, android-intent, skype, android-webview

I need to invoke skype application and make a call from skype when a 'skype me' link (eg: skype://1866012345) is clicked from a webview. Can someone help how to do this?

I tried the following:

Downloaded skype application from market (in my driod 2.2).
When launching skype, the package invoked is 'skype.android.raider' - as per ADB logs.
So I tried invoking a ACTION_VIEW intent with cmp=com.skype.raider/.ui.call.SplashScreenActivity or cmp=com.skype.raider/.ui.call.SkypeOutCallActivity
and data=Uri.parse("skype://1866012345"). These did not work.

(I also did find a few posts suggesting to use skypelite component, but I guess I should ve skype lite installed for that, which could not find in the market. I assume skype lite is not in market anymore.)

(Also, i have to be able to make a phone call or email when corresponding links are clicked from WebView. As of now, I have added custom handling for each of these, but wondering if webview by default would not support it. Is there any webview setting to be enabled t do this? Any idea??)

thanks!

Comment: sorry you don't need to add
i.setData(Uri.parse("skype:econt-bg"));

Comment: Seems it is not feasible at this moment. I had contacted Skype support and here is part of the response I got. 

*'Unfortunatley it is at the moment not possible to include Skype to other app, nor invoke Skype from them.
However we suggest that you sign yourself up to our developer zone which can be accessed from here: http://developer.skype.com, which allows you to develop new apps and features for Skype and with Skype.
Unfortunatley we are also not able to provide you with any code samples. '*

Answer (score 0):

Unless they're doing intent filtering or using custom permissions to disallow you from starting one of their activities then it is still possible. You have to start their activity explicitly as they start it doing the exact same action.

I've done it with the official Facebook app to launch viewing a profile directly.